# Python SSL import error

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ssl

I can't import ssl in python, it gives me an error.

Code:

```
import ssl
```

Output (Sublime Text 3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 138, in <module>
    from socket import socket, _fileobject, _delegate_methods, error as socket_error
ImportError: cannot import name socket
```

I am using Kali Linux, python's version is 2.7.12+

My sources.list file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160830-11:29]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160830-11:29]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Command line:

```
root@PYTH:~/Desktop# python asd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 137, in <module>
    from socket import socket, _fileobject, _delegate_methods, error as socket_error
ImportError: cannot import name socket

root@PYTH:~/Desktop# python3 asd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 144, in <module>
    from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, create_connection
ImportError: cannot import name 'socket'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 739, in <module>
    class HTTPConnection:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 749, in HTTPConnection
    def __init__(self, host, port=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 144, in <module>
    from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, create_connection
ImportError: cannot import name 'socket'
```

python command line:

```
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Aug  4 2016, 20:04:34) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160724] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 137, in <module>
    from socket import socket, _fileobject, _delegate_methods, error as socket_error
ImportError: cannot import name socket
>>> print(socket)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
>>> print(dir(socket))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

Comment: Start python and in its console type (each command on one line): `import socket` then `print(socket)` and then `print(dir(socket))`, and paste the outputs. But the error is strange: where do you have the `import ssl` statement? And the line numbers are strange as well. Did you by any chance modified _socket.py_ (from _Python_ library)? Or you have your own file called _socket.py_? If so, __rename it__ since it's a standard _Python_ module name.

Comment: No, i didn't modify the python library.. I modified my question, the answer to your question is now there.

Comment: Seems like you still have a file called _socket(.py/.pyc/.so)_ in _Python_ module search path (next to _asd.py_ maybe). Modify _asd.py_ and add the following (4) lines (at __its beginning__): `import socket`,`print(socket)`, `import sys`, `print(sys.path)`, and paste the output (without any exceptions).

Comment: Now it fixed it! Thanks! Also, I had to restart the PC.. (i don't know why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your file is named `socket.py`, and this produces the error (python confuses the name of your file with another `socket`, part of `ssl` module which it needs to import, thus having the namespace type of error).

Rename your file to something else (`my_socket.py`) and the problem should go away.

Comment: That fixed my socket import problem, but not the ssl

Comment: True, the error in your current question is caused by the namespace conflict, not the ssl. Please, provide more details about the new error message (if there is one), or the expected behaviour you are missing.

Comment: There's no change, the problem still exists... There's no new :) error message, i think i'll reinstall the whole OS... I tried everything, but python is evil...

Answer (score 1):

Below link will sloves your problem

https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/